# How do I insert a number into current value in mysql column

Tags: mysql

Current db `birthday`

```
ID  OldBirthday   NewBirthday
------------------------------ 
1   810401    
2   821112    
3   830725
```

Now I want copy from `OldBirthday`  to `NewBirthday` with adding `19` at beginning.

Results should be

```
ID  OldBirthday   NewBirthday
------------------------------ 
1   810401        19810401
2   821112        19821112    
3   830725        19830725
```

Let me know..

```
UPDATE birthday 
SET NewBirthday = OldBirthday
```

Comment: What data type are OldBirthday and NewBirthday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE birthday SET NewBirthday = (OldBirthday + 19000000)
```

Comment: If the datatypes are strings, you'd want to use `'19'||OldBirthday` on the right side.

Comment: Right, depends on the DataType - those look like ints. If these are really birthday, you probably want to store these as dates though :)